# I am confused with how lifecycleScope in android studio works

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I am confused about how flow.collect works. Because in the lifecycleScope below I already say that a should be assigned by the value of data in my database. However, the value of a is still the string of "Hi" instead of "Hello".

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private var a: String = "Hi"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding?.root)

    val somethingDao = SomethingDatabase.getDatabase(this).somethingDao()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        somethingDao.insert(SomethingModel("Hello"))
        somethingDao.fetchAllSomething().collect {
            a = it[it.size - 1].name
        }
    }

    println(a)

}
}
```

this is all of the information in my database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lifecycleScope.launch will start a coroutine, to make it simple the code inside lifecycleScope.launch will be executed in another thread and it will take some time until inserting data and reading it from database, but **println(a)** is on the main thread so it will be executed before this line **a = it[it.size - 1].name**, so your **println(a)** should be inside **lifecycleScope.launch** like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private var a: String = "Hi"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding?.root)

        val somethingDao = SomethingDatabase.getDatabase(this).somethingDao()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            somethingDao.insert(SomethingModel("Hello"))
            somethingDao.fetchAllSomething().collect {
                a = it[it.size - 1].name
                println(a)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: take a look on kotlin coroutines to better understand

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed Rejeb. Anyways, can we change the data of the variable a in lifecycleScope? Because the only way to get the data and assign it to the variable a is within lifecycleScope which does not affect the data on main thread. I just want to find the way to change the data in lifecycleScope and might as well change the value of variable a on main thread

Comment: The best practice is to change data and get it inside the lifecycleScope, you can do anything with the data inside the lifecycleScope